# Unique bug in devexpress' combo box, 2 out of 131 rows that were added seemed to have extra characters (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox, devexpress

This is the first time I've experienced something like this. As far as I know I've done everything as they should be and for the most part it did output what I wanted but somehow there were unique bugs that seemed impossible.

It all started with a combo box that I populated with this code:

```
items.Add(new { Text = dr4["item_name"], Value = dr4["item_id"] });
```

It did the trick and filled the combo box with the 131 rows of item names in the combo box. But while scrolling inside the combo box, I found two items that were occupying two lines. I don't know how this happened, all of the items that were inserted in that combo box underwent the exact same way since I looped the code above so the problem could have not been from there. I double checked my database to see if I had some extra spaces or characters but they didn't and was normal as the rest of the 129 rows.

I tried creating a textbox and tried to fill it with both the combo box's text and value using this code:

```
textBox.Text = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() + comboBox.Text.ToString();
```

I had some interesting results. The 129 rows of data appeared right next to each other (not even a space) BUT the 2 specific rows of data appeared as if someone pressed enter after the selected value was printed.

For the sake of further explanation, let's say the selected value was "5" and the text was "This is number 5":

Now, the textbox's text output from the 129 rows were:

`5This is number 5`

While the textbox's text output from the 2 other rows where:

`5
This is number 5`

Now I don't know how this is happening and can't even explain it myself as they're both all from the same table, it couldn't be their length because there are longer texts from the other text from the 129 rows than the 2 other rows that's behaving unexpectedly.

I can't understand where are they getting this extra characters from, there doesn't seem to be any pattern. I think this has something to do with the devexpress combo box I'm using. I've tried populating a normal visual studio's combo box and it produced my desired output, all of the 131 items inside the combo box were normal.

Comment: I already fixed it, I don't know but somehow my database was buggy. The item name has three words. I deleted the item name and retyped it to no avail. Out of boredom and desperation, I tried to remove the first two words and suddenly it ran fine and only consumed one line in the combo box. Then out of curiosity, I retyped the first two words again and lo and behold, it was now working. I did the same thing with the other item and it worked again. This was some creepy bug.

Comment: just delete then :-p

Comment: Yup, was pretty weird though as it looked normal like the rest of the rows but somehow it was translating to a line break then the words when c/sql interprets them.

Comment: I meant *delete the question*, cause it can't really help someone else

Comment: I beg to differ, this has happened to me and might happen to someone else so let's just keep it here. I'd rather have this minuscule problem with a solution handy for the future if ever someone experiences the same problem because trust me it took days to finish this as the solution didn't even make sense as the rows looked normal.